# Import Root CA into Trusted Root Certificate Store from a script

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate, pki

We're looking into the possibility of deploying our enterprise CA to users at their homes, and we're looking for a method to programmatically install a root CA.

I noticed certutil isn't included on the default XP install.

Does anyone know of a similar utility that can import certificates into certificate stores without prompting the user for any information?

We need to target XP, Vista, and 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lookup CEnroll for XP, I believe it's deprecated in Vista and Windows 7 though.

This might help with the Vista/7 problem.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa374863.aspx